# Calculate the numbers in Scala

Tags: scala

I can calculate the expressions, and term but I don't understand what is tregonometric functions. Are they Expressions or Terms or Items? How to write the algorithm of calculation of Pi and tregonometric functions. Cos, sin....
Please if you know give me a hint.

Answer (score 5):

Try a web search again, this time using the correct spelling "trigonometric functions".  Algorithms for calculations like this date back at least to ancient Greece and you'll find them in a great many maths textbooks.

I suggest you try to do your own homework, then (and only then) come back to stack overflow if you have some particular issue with Scala syntax that prevents you from implementing your chosen algorithm.  In the meantime, this isn't a proper or valid question.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your answer. I will search about algorithms and ask here again with more proper question.